# Spring Rest Respository Collection name case sensitivity

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I am using Spring Boot and MongoDB, and am trying to expose them over REST using Spring Rest Repositories.

I have a Mongo collection called `user` and the Java domain model class called `User`. My Rest Repository looks like this:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(  collectionResourceRel = "users", path = "users")
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {

    public User findByEmail(@Param("email") String email);

}
```

With this in place, I get the advertised benefits of the resource getting automatically exposed over REST. GET, PUT, POST all that jazz.

What I find though is that when I rename the Mongo collection to `User`, it doesn't find records on the `/users` endpoint. It is almost as if Spring REST Repositories assumes that the collection name will be in lowercase (yes, I did come across the documentation here - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/)

> Spring Data REST exposes a collection resource named after the uncapitalized, pluralized version of the domain class the exported repository is handling. Both the name of the resource and the path can be customized using the @RepositoryRestResource on the repository interface.

What I am after is a way to get this configured so that I can use a collection name like `User` instead of `user`.

I have searched a fair bit, but haven't been able to come up with answers.

Any help much appreciated!
Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried changing `collectionResourceRel = "users"` to `collectionResourceRel = "Users"` as the docs suggest?

Comment: In much the same sentiment as the comment just added, instead of telling us *"I followed the guide"* show us exactly what you did by providing the necessary code/configuration within the question itself. It kind of sounds like your changed both the `collectionResourceRel` and the `path`, when you're only meant to change one of them. Not that I'm going to recommend starting a collection name with an uppercase character anyway, since that goes against common conventions.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thanks for the quick reply. Yes, tried it but no luck! In fact, when the Mongo collection name is `users`, it works regardless of whether `collectionResourceRel` is `users` or `Users` :(

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn, yes, I agree. Unfortunately, I don't have direct control on being able to change the case of the collection :( And no, I didn't change the `path`, just `collectionResourceRel`

Comment: You agree to what exactly? We are pretty much asking you to **show your code** instead of just repeating "did that" or "followed that". [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53423947/edit) and show us exactly what you did.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem,
In my case I have annotated the User class with @Document but I was missing to add the value :

```
@Document("User")
```

javadoc of value attribute:

> The collection the document representing the entity is supposed to be
> stored in. If not configured, a default collection name will be
> derived from the type's name.

So by default if not configured, seems to use the Class name in lowerCamelCase.